Make Edge Slide Clamp Off By Default
Is there a way to do this? The edge slide tool seems to reset with every use, and setting the current scene with the checkbox unticked as a startup file does not seem to do anything.

You can change the default keymap.

Got in Edit > Preferences > Keymap.
Search for "Edge Slide"
Uncheck "Clamp"

Click the hamburger menu in the bottom left corner > Save Preferences.

You can also do the same for the vertex slide:

That being said, this one is more often accessed as an option of the Move operator instead, but this one doesn't have exposed options in the keymap:

